# How many pixels tall is the Google logo in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need a `div` to be laid just above the logo so that I'm not breaking any rules with the API. Or am I able to move the logo/change the size manually?

Comment: Well, you can check this [Guidelines](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html) on how to use Google Maps in your Application. For your question, am I able to move the logo/change the size manually? Yes, you can move the logo and for it's size, the Google Logo must be the largest logo in your Maps API Implementation, site, or other propert(ies) (except as displayed in the map image itself); You can read more about it in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#8-licenses-from-google-to-you).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_4. Seems to be prohibited to change any attribution.